# Require less overlap for jquery droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I am setting up a draggable interface using jquery to do my drag/drop operations.  I have a tall object (400px x 50px) that I want to drop into a small anchor (100px x 100px).  It seems that in order for the "drop" and "over" events to fire, at least half the dragging container must be inside the bounds of the droppable container, which doesn't happen in this case because the dragging container is so much bigger.  Is there a way to lessen this restriction so that these events will fire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `tolerance` option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-tolerance

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ tolerance: "touch" });
```

You may also like the `pointer` value:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ tolerance: "pointer" });
```

**Update**

If you want to limit certain droppables to only drop in a specific drop-zone then you can set the `scope` option:

```
$( ".selector-1" ).droppable({ scope: "tasks" });
$( ".selector-2" ).draggable({ scope: "tasks" });
```

The same documentation link as above will offer more info about this option as well.

Comment: Touch is actually the option I was looking for, but is there a way to force it to select only one droppable container?  the container is big enough that it can span the distance between multiple anchors.

Comment: See the **update** to my answer, you're most likely wanting to use the `scope` option.

Comment: Good thought but that's not quite it.  I thought greedy might do it but that's only for nested controls.  I think I can code around it, I was just looking for a quick answer.  Thanks!